# Adverb for "Cannot be topped"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a good adverb to indicate an attribute that cannot be improved upon?

I wanted '**untoppably**' to be a word, but it isn't.

**Optimally** and its synonyms come to mind, but it doesn't really have the best fit for the phrase I have in mind:

> I’ve thought up a pretty neat method for completely eliminating dynamic cell references. I wrote it down for later. You can look forward to an [untoppably] fast version whenever I get a free week to implement it. (Could be a month, could be a year)

Comment: Close to what you mean, I like "sans-pareil."  (Even though it's basically impossible to pronounce!)

Comment: Yes well, being French, that's right up my alley!

Comment: In this context I wouldn't claim that it's impossible to optimize further. Just say it's optimized. "You can look forward to an optimized version whenever ...".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Optimally** is probably the most accurate word in general, but a good fit for the phrase you give is [**unbeatably**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unbeatably):

> You can look forward to an unbeatably fast version.

Comment: That's actually a very good fit! I'll give a chance for other answers to come in, but this could be the accepted solution for sure.

Answer (score 7):

I think insurmountably would also be a decent answer.

Comment: True, although it tends to have negative connotations. Something that is insurmountable is not generally regarded as "the best thing possible", it's regarded as "something bad that can't be overcome"

Comment: I think that connotation can go both ways. You can also say that someone has an insurmountable lead, which sounds like a good thing. In this case, if you simply place "insurmountably" in the test sentence you gave, I think it will do the job.

Comment: Good example, I'll hand out points for that.

Answer (score 2):

Some more possibilities:

incomparably
supremely
exceedingly
transcendently
inimitably
unsurpassably
uniquely
unapproachably
peerlessly
unmatchably
invincibly
unsurpassedly

Answer (score 1):

The adverb I would use is insuperably. From the adjective insuperable. (not "toppable")